# Deleting labels

Tags: javascript, flipclock

How can I delete labels in flipclock? I'm taking about minutes and seconds. Removing these 2 lines solved the problem but it also deletes 2 dots separating minutes and seconds.

```
$(this.createDivider('Seconds')).insertBefore(this.lists[this.lists.length - 2].$el);
            $(this.createDivider('Minutes')).insertBefore(this.lists[this.lists.length - 4].$el);
```

Comment: Have you tried simply passing an empty string to the `createDivider` method …?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the example on http://flipclockjs.com/, this creates the following HTML structure for each “divider”:

```
<span class="flip-clock-divider minutes">
  <span class="flip-clock-label">Minutes</span>
  <span class="flip-clock-dot top"></span>
  <span class="flip-clock-dot bottom"></span>
</span>
```

So if you just remove those calls completely, the dots will be missing as well.

But if you just pass an empty string to the method, `this.createDivider('')`, it should simply create the `.flip-clock-label` element with no text content - and that should be enough to achieve what you want.